# How to overwrite multiple lines printed to the console?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, console

I would like to print out several lines to my console and then over write those lines when I print again.  In the past I have done something similar with a single line by doing this:

```
print(datetime.datetime.now(), end='\r')
```

In my current situation when I execute:

```
output = """1
2
3"""
print(output, end='\r')
output = """4
5
6"""
print(output, end='\r')
```

it displays:

```
1
2
4
5
6
```

when I really want:

```
4
5
6
```

As you can see it overwrites the last line of output from the first print statement (`3`) but not the first two lines.  Is it possible to use `print` to get my desired output?  I am currently using Python 3, but would be willing to go back to python 2.7 if there was an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want control of more than the current line, take a look at the curses library.  Python 2.X shipped with a wrapper module.  I don’t know if Python 3.X does.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html

EDIT:  yes, it is still in 3.X.  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/curses.html

Comment: Wow Curses seems pretty powerful.  I think it would definitely accomplish what i'm trying to do but it almost seems like overkill.  Hoping to find something that is a little simpler if possible but good to know I can fall back to this if need be.